# Suitable Record Type for a web server using a non-standard port?

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-proxy, a-record

I need to set up some servers that must be ran on ports above 5000. (This is a request from the client for this job, due to internal policies, and I can't do anything about it). What is concerning me is that, among other things, I have to set up a web server to run on a port different than 80, but the site must still be able to receive requests like example.com/contact and example.com/register . Since it will not operate on port 80, I won't be able to use A Record. So... is it even possible to do this job? I could configure Apache to use 5080, or whatever they want, but then what? How could people outside the LAN access it by the address example.com/whatever ?

Comment: You won't. You will have to use the port number in the URL and if the client doesn't like that, well, too bad because it was his requirement!

Comment: @MichaelHampton hahaha this company is so picky that I wish I could say that to them.

Comment: The suitable record type _would_ be `SRV`, but the draft standard (http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-andrews-http-srv-02) to use that for HTTP has expired and I don't know if anything in wide use implements it anyway. So this comment is of no help at all to you, it's just a sad note on what might have been a clean and useful solution.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this job, but not just with a DNS entry. You need to have a firewall in front of the web server that is able to do a port forward/modification. Then a request to `example.com/contact` can before forwarded to port 5080 on your Apache server's internal IP address as it passes through the firewall, or a request to `example.net/register` could be forwarded to port 5180 on the same Apache server, or port 5080 on a completely different server, depending on how you want to set it up.

This is often called a [Reverse Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy).

Depending on the capabilities of the reverse proxy firewall you will likely need a different domain name for each internal port or address (notice the .net vs .com in the examples above), especially if you want to handle https traffic, and those domains may even need to point to a different public IP addresses you control.

---

Since this won't work, you could try an off-site web server that functions similarly to a URL shortening service like bit.ly. The off-site web server could receive a request from the user for addresses like `example.com/register` and respond with an http 301 redirect for `example.net:5080/register`. Just about any web browser from the IE 5/Netscape 4.3 era and on will follow this, and it will be mostly transparent to the user.

Comment: Your solution is very smart, but as I as I was told, the main reason they require all services to operate on 5000+ is because of firewall polices, so I can not propose any changes to their firewall. I would have to set up this frontal firewall outside the company, like using a Digital Ocean account or something like that. Is there any out-of-the-box solution for this reverse proxy procedure? I would rather outsource this, if possible.

Comment: You can put a reverse proxy off site, and forward to their systems. I'm not familiar with a service that will do this out of the box, though. But if you have to host something off-site, why not just host apache there?

Comment: Maybe a custom url shortening service that just http-redirects to something with the 5000+ port number?

Comment: Some features will be running only locally (e.g.: stock management), other will be available publically (e.g.: selling stuff) and both features are related, so I think it's easier to create the server locally and outsource the IP:Port redirecting. How would a url shortening work? Will it allow to perform requests like example.com/register ?

Comment: For the url "shortening", you just have an offsite http server that takes any requests it it recieves and return and an http 301 redirect to the new address. So you set up the service so it receives a request at `example.com/register` and responds with an http 301 redirect to `example.net:5080/register`

Comment: that's interesting, but how would that work exactly? If I do a HTTP 301 redirect from `example.com` to `example.net:5000`, will it automatically redirect anything else in the url properly? For example, would `example.com/whatever` be automatically redirected to `example.net:5000/whatever` too? The `whatever` part is dinamic and unpredictable to me. It could be dates, bar codes etc.

Comment: You make a custom 404 page that overrides the 404 response with a 301 to the new server:port with the same relative path as the original.